# AngularFire2 DB call is not executed

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i am trying to filter a DB List from Angularfire2 in Typescript to get a specific Record.

```
AddAppointment(date:Date){
let existingAppointment = this.af.database.list(this.appointmentDbRoute).map(values => {
  let filtered = values.filter(filter => filter.Date === date);
  return filtered;
})};
```

The Problem is : The map Method is not Executed . I can do what i want, its not executing, only when i add the subscribe function in the End.
In all Tutorials ony the Map Method is called.

I am using the Version angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.2

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this instead

```
this.items = af.database.list('this.appointmentDbRoute', { preserveSnapshot: true });
this.items
  .subscribe(snapshots => {
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      // DO SOME FILTERING HERE...
    });
  })
```

from documentation here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md

you are trying to call map on a `FirebaseObservable` since your call

`this.af.database.list(this.appointmentDbRoute)`

returns a `FirebaseObservable` you need to `subscribe` to get results and then perform the filtering

Comment: Hi Aaron , ok now im getting it : there must be a subscriber to fetch Data , a ngFor or manually subscribe to this . Thanks a lot !